# python path error

Tags: python, macos

I had two version of python.. python 2.6 and python 2.7

I just now deleted python 2.6 (rather in very unsafe way)..

Now when I type python, I get this error:

```
 python: VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION environment variable error (ignored)
python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory
```

My python 2.7 is installed in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

When i do which python

I get /usr/bin/python

How do i resolve this mess I have created.

Comment: How did you delete it? Also can you go to /usr/bin/ and do ls -all | grep python and show us what it has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you deleted the Apple-supplied Python 2.6.  You shouldn't have done that.  Never delete files in `/usr`, other than `/usr/local`, or in `/System/Library`.  When you install another framework version of Python, like you did with the Python 2.7 into `/Library/Frameworks`, the way to manage which one you use is by managing your shell `PATH` environment variable, not by attempting to modify `/usr/bin/python`.  You have three primary options now: (1) live without the Apple-supplied Python 2.6 until your next OS X upgrade and hope that no other Apple-supplied utilities you need depend on it; or (2) reinstall all of OS X; or (3) if you remember exactly what you deleted and have a full backup, attempt to restore the deleted files.  To use the newer Python 2.7, put it first on your path, for example:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Adding this export to the path helped the system recognize Django again. Now I could for example do django-admin.py and it works. Thank ou...

Comment: how can even not remember what i have done cause i bought second laptop